# Linking to the user's profile page using ajax autocomplete option

Tags: php, ajax

In my ajax autocomplete page, it will show the user's first name and last name.

**But i  want to make a link to the user's profile page (profile.php) where it will display the user's details if we pass the user's unique id (username).**

**How can i do this ?**

Here is my ajax code which works perfectly.

**index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".search").keyup(function() 
{ 
var searchid = $(this).val();
var dataString = 'search='+ searchid;
if(searchid!='')
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "search.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
    $("#result").html(html).show();
    }
    });
}return false;    
});

jQuery("#result").live("click",function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
    $('#searchid').val(decoded);
});
jQuery(document).live("click", function(e) { 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
    jQuery("#result").fadeOut(); 
    }
});
$('#searchid').click(function(){
    jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
});
});
```

**search.php**

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if($_POST)
{
$q=$_POST['search'];
$sql_res=mysql_query("select id,name,email from autocomplete where name like '%$q%' or email like '%$q%' order by id LIMIT 5");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_res))
{
$username=$row['name'];
$email=$row['email'];
$b_username='<strong>'.$q.'</strong>';
$b_email='<strong>'.$q.'</strong>';
$final_username = str_ireplace($q, $b_username, $username);
$final_email = str_ireplace($q, $b_email, $email);
?>
<div class="show" align="left">
<?php echo $final_username; ?>
</span>&nbsp;<br/><?php echo $final_email; ?><br/>
</div>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple and clear.

If you want to add the link to profile.php page in the auto suggestion.

Here is the workaround.

You should probably add

```
<a href="profile.php?username=<? echo $user; ?>">
```

in the `search.php`. and there is no changes to be done in the `index.php.`